# Sidekiq-scheduler - why is daily cron job skipping days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq

A task scheduled using sidekiq-scheduler doesn't run daily as it should. With 6 variables in the cron, I'm under the impression this task should be running at 00:05 daily. The "Last Time" run is two days ago (screenshot provided). The schedule for this task:

```
reminder_queuer:
  cron: '0 5 0 * * *'
  class: ReminderQueuer
```

Procfile contains the below, .yml has the schedule.

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

The task runs most days, but I came across this because it missed an update recently. Other scheduled similarly have the same issue. This task queues a weekly email and worked fine last week.

I do have one task with a `0 0 */12 * * *` schedule that has no issues (runs every 12 hrs).

[looks like this in sidekiq web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnPGf.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run your cron at 00:05 everyday, in my opinion it should looks like this below:

**cron: '5 0 * * *'**

```
5 means minutes, 0 means hour and stars mean everyday
```

Comment: sidekiq-scheduler's cron utility has seconds resolution. So my set up mentioned above should be running 00:05:00 everyday